# reading an object with dynamic array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-memory-allocation, file-handling, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to read the file of objects(in my case patients) and make a dynamic array of them.
 I used counter to count the objects stored in the file and create an array with respect to that  counter size.
My problem is as an out put i'm getting only the last item i stored in file multiple times(for example if my counter is 6 the out put is 6 times the last item was stored in file).

```
  void patient::read_patient_DB()
    {   int counter = 0;
       fstream fp;
      patient p;
    cout << "\n\n\n\t\tDISPLAY ALL RECORD !!!\n\n";
    fp.open("patient.dat", ios:: in );
    while (fp.read((char *) & p, sizeof(patient)))
    {
        counter++;


    }
    cout<<"----The out patient group has ["<<counter<<"] data recorded----"<<endl;
    patient * pointer = new patient[counter];
    for(int i = 0;i <counter;i++)
    {
      pointer[i] = p;
     pointer[i].preview();

    }


    delete [] pointer;
    fp.close();

    }
```

Comment: In C++, "dynamic array" is spelled `std::vector`. With it, you won't need to count the records beforehand.

Comment: `pointer[i] = p;` -- so you set every value in the array to the same `p`, and you're wondering why every value in the array is the same? Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is as an out put i'm getting only the last item i stored in file multiple times

This makes sense considering that you never modify `p` between each `pointer[i] = p`. You need to do something like this:

```
while(read_from_file(p)) {
    pointer[i++] = p;
}
```